# Do I need Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms and Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, project.json

In a new ASP.NET Core RC2 class library, I have the following project.json file, where I have tried to follow the docs on [How to trim your package dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/reducing-dependencies).

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.3"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.5": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.0.1-rc2-24027",
        "Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime": "1.0.2-rc2-24027",
        "System.Xml.XDocument": "4.0.11-rc2-24027"
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    },
    "net461": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.ServiceModel": "",
        "System.Xml": "",
        "System.Xml.Linq": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I have tried removing `Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms` and `Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime`, everything still works. This is probably because the Microsoft dependencies also specify these. What are these dependencies for and should I be explicit and keep them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What purpose do the packages have:

- `Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms` is essentially only a json files which specifies the [runtime identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/rid-catalog) (RIDs). These Ids (e.g. `osx.10.10-x64` or `win7-x86`) are used when platform specific code needs to be deployed (e.g. a special compiled CoreCLR or platform specific compression or crypto library). It forms a kind of tree which allows more generic platform patterns (like `linux` which is later the parent for e.g. `rhel` which again is the parent for a specific supported version `rhel-7.1-x64`). So When someone builds a NuGet, you can add an artifiact like an assembly which is deployed on all linux machines (e.g. doing P/Invoke against the standard linux apis) or a specific linux distribution (e.g. using a special RedHat feature).
- `Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime` is a trickier story. It is used to lookup the right runtime for your platform.

Should you keep them: Since you do not use them directly, adding these dependencies explicitly does not bring any benefit to my understanding.